# How to filter out a particular value from PS output

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-cmdlet, powercli

I am running a PS command `get-Keyproperty` which is returning result in table format at below"

```
Key                  Label                          Policy     Running  Required
---                  -----                          ------     -------  --------
abc                 UI                               on         True     False  
efg                 UI                               off        True     False
```

I want to retrieve value of `Policy` which is `on`

How to retrieve `Policy` value of `abc` `Key`?

I am running `get-Keyproperty | Select-Object abc` but it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the value of `Policy` try to run

```
Get-Keyproperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Policy
```

Even though the command above is the recommended way, you can also get the same result with `(Get-Keyproperty).Policy`.

If you want to check if the value matches "on" just do `(Get-Keyproperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Policy) -eq "on"`

If you want the `Policy` Value of a certain entry you can either:

1. Choose the entry over its position in the table

   `(Get-Keyproperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Policy)[0]`
2. Or by finding it over its value of `Key`

   `Get-Keyproperty | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq "abc" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Policy`

   As mentioned in the comments, a shorter way of the same command is

   `(Get-Keyproperty | ? Key -eq "abc").Policy`

   `?` is an alias (`Get-Alias ?`) and the `{script block}` is only neccessary for more complex expressions which then requires the `$_.Key` or `$PSItem.Key`*(introduced in PSv3)* notation; which both are synonym for the current object in the pipeline . See `Get-Help Where-Object`.

Comment: How to retrieve `Policy` value of `abc` `Key`?

Comment: @meallhour I edited the answer, I hope this solves your questions.

Comment: Just a shorter/aliased way to get the same `(Get-Keyproperty | ? Key -eq "abc").Policy`

Comment: @LotPings yeah thx, i added it to the answer with an short explanation.

Comment: The `?` **IS** an alias (`Get-Alias ?`) and the `{script block}` is only neccessary for more complex expressions which then requires the $_.Key notation which itself is an alias for $PSItem.Key. See `Get-Help Where-Object`

Comment: @LotPings thanks for the clearing.
Is it ok if I copy the comment into the last line of the answer for a better overall view?

Comment: Of course. With a correction, `$_` and `$PSItem` are both synonym for current object in the pipeline while the latter was introduced with PSv3 to make code more readable and is to my experience rarely used.